# Python Dictionary: Create a list for all keys in dict, another for all values in dict

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary which looks like this:

`Counter({'firstKey': 1708, 'secondKey': 1589, 'thirdKey': 1424})`

I would like to have two lists:

First list should list all keys:

`['firstKey', 'secondKey', 'thirdKey']`

Second list should list all values:

`[1708, 1589, 1424]`

Please help

Comment: `your_dict.keys()` and `your_dict.values()`

Comment: @Minu That wouldn't quite to do what they want, since those return `dict_keys` and `dict_values` objects, not lists, (at least in Python3) but they can be easily converted like said in answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [`list(Counter.keys())` and `list(Counter.values())`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp)

```
>>> counter= Counter({'firstKey': 1708, 'secondKey': 1589, 'thirdKey': 1424})
>>> Keys = list(counter.keys())
>>> Keys
['firstKey', 'secondKey', 'thirdKey']
>>> Vals = list(counter.values())
>>> Vals
[1708, 1589, 1424]
>>>
```

Answer (score 3):

Using [`dict.keys()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.keys) and [`dict.values()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.values) and casting them to `list`:

```
d = {'firstKey': 1708, 'secondKey': 1589, 'thirdKey': 1424}

print(list(d.keys()))
print(list(d.values()))
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
['firstKey', 'thirdKey', 'secondKey']                                                                                                                          
[1708, 1424, 1589]
```

Answer (score 2):

You could assign the two list variables in one line like this:

```
d = Counter({'firstKey': 1708, 'secondKey': 1589, 'thirdKey': 1424})

keys,values = map(list,zip(*d.items()))
```

output:

```
print(keys)
print(values)

['firstKey', 'secondKey', 'thirdKey']
[1708, 1589, 1424]
```

Answer (score 1):

Cast `list()` to the dictionary to get the keys in a list, and cast `list()` to the [`dict.values()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.values) to get the values in a list:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> d = Counter({'firstKey': 1708, 'secondKey': 1589, 'thirdKey': 1424})
>>> l1 = list(d)
>>> l1
['firstKey', 'secondKey', 'thirdKey']
>>> l2 = list(d.values())
>>> l2
[1708, 1589, 1424]
```

Could also use [`dict.keys()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.keys):

```
>>> l1 = list(d.keys())
>>> l1
['firstKey', 'secondKey', 'thirdKey']
```

But not really needed since `list(d)` will give you the keys by default.